# At WooCommerce, I want products with zero price to be moved to the bottom of the list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

my site use theme AVADA and woocommerce
The following file
wp-content/themes/Avada/templates/wc-catalog-ordering.php
I copied it into the child's theme
To make the price from the lowest to the highest, The following code

```
<li class="<?php echo ( 'price' === $pob || 'price-desc' === $pob ) ? 'current' : ''; ?>">
<?php /* translators: Name, Price, Date etc. */ ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url_raw( fusion_add_url_parameter( $query_string, 'product_orderby', 'price' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Sort by %s', 'Avada' ), '<strong>' . esc_attr__( 'Price', 'Avada' ) . '</strong>' ); ?></a>
</li>
```

I changed that

```
<li class="<?php echo ( 'price' === $pob || 'price-desc' === $pob ) ? 'current' : ''; ?>">
<?php /* translators: Name, Price, Date etc. */ ?>
<a href="?product_orderby=price&product_order=asc">price Lowest to Highest</a>
</li>
```

I want zero price products to be moved to the bottom of the list
This means that first the products are displayed at a high price and then the products with a zero price are displayed

Answer (score 0):

The order should be **desc**. The url parameters are built in the switch-case statements. have a look throught.

Also, use the theme's default function `fusion_add_url_parameter` for url building.
try using this for desc order.

```
<li class="<?php echo ( 'price' === $pob || 'price-desc' === $pob ) ? 'current' : ''; ?>""><a href="' . fusion_add_url_parameter($query_string, 'product_order', 'desc') . '">Price Lowest to Highest</a></li>;
```